# Does Python cache repeatedly accessed files?

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering if Python is smart enough enough to cache repeatedly accessed files, e.g. when reading the same CSV with pandas or unpickling the same file multiple times.

Is this even Python's responsibility, or should the operating system take care of it?

Comment: No it does not. The OS **does**.

Comment: No, Python won't cache them. What if they have changed in the meantime, wouldn't you want to know? Rather, you should write code that deals with files (and other relatively slow IO operations) more sensibly.

Comment: If you try to write a non too small file, then write a timing function that simply computes the time taken to read the file, and try to read the file multiple times *in a loop* you'll see that the timings drop (I just tried on my linux box and the timings halved after 5 iterations)  Note however that the cache could be cleared quite quickly, so if the same file is read after like 10 or 30 seconds it may not be in any cache.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you should only change your code if you find that the OS's file caching is actually inadequate.

Comment: @nekomatic I wouldn't rely on an OS implementation detail if I could possibly avoid it. That can put limits on the platforms to which you can deploy your code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe However, if you don't have control over other processes that work with the file, OS will be your lowest common denominator. Relying on OS details sure does put some limits on portability but you may find that those limits are pretty wide and you don't need to support so many platforms.

It's a tradeoff and if you can sacrifice portability to platforms you don't intend to support for performance on platforms you do support, then it's a deal.

Comment: @Daerdemandt that's a fair point, but I would still err on the side of writing code that's thoughtful about when and how it reads files, rather than writing bad code and relying on the OS to bail me out!

Comment: By the way, see [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) and other 3rd party libraries, e.g. [**cached-property**](https://github.com/pydanny/cached-property).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Python is just a language and doesn't really do anything on its own. A particular Python library might implement caching, but the standard functions you use to open and read files don't do so. The higher-level file-loading functions in Pandas and the CSV module don't do any caching either.

The operating system might do some caching of its own, but you can't control that from within Python.

Answer (score 1):

[As David Z said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38145044/4576519), Python does not cache on its own. If you want to cache from within Python, the easiest way is to use [functoons.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache). You can then decorate your own file reading function:

```py
import functools

@functools.lru_cache
def read_file (path):
    f = open(path, "r")
    return f.read()
```

By default `maxsize=128`, but you can increase it if you want to keep more files in cache. If you don't want a maximum cache size, use [functools.cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) instead.